# SQL IF/Case in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert, case

I am trying to create procedure which will insert  two values in my Pickup table.

```
create procedure sp_InsertPickup
@ClientID int,
@PickupDate date 
as 
insert into Pickup (ClientID ,PickupDate )values (@ClientID,@PickupDate)
```

However I need check if this client  already did pickup in this month (record in table)it should not insert any new records it table.
example if this data in table

```
ClientID PickupDate
11       03-01-2013
```

And I want insert `ClientId 11 and new PickupDate 03-24-2013` it should  just not insert  because this person already did pickup this month. 
Any Ideas how to implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in that case, use a `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertPickup
    @ClientID int,
    @PickupDate date 
AS
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Pickup 
                  WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
                    AND MONTH(PickupDate) = MONTH(@PickupDate) 
                    AND YEAR(PickupDate) = YEAR(@PickupDate) )
      INSERT INTO Pickup (ClientID, PickupDate)
      VALUES (@ClientID, @PickupDate)
```

You might want to somehow indicate to the caller that there was no data inserted, due to the fact it already exists....

As a side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: hmmm MONTH gives 1-12, not quite what is needed

Comment: But way all books recommend use `sp_` in stored procedure names?

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: care to share at least one book that does recommend `sp_` as stored procedure prefix? I'd be curious to know...

Comment: What if there was an insert for same month last year?

Comment: @marc_s In your aproach the system just  checking if same date in system byt if i insert  other date it insert with out problem .

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: I don't understand what you're saying... you said in your question that you want to avoid inserting a new row if one for the customer already exists in this month - does my solution do that or not?

Comment: @marc_s Sorry Marc let me rephrase my question  Client  shouldn't be inserted in table if they have pickup record in this month, but it should allowed to insert new record in same month next year.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: ok - but with my code, this ***IS*** possible - no?? It works - I just tested it - no problem to insert a pickup for the current date, but next year (unless that entry also already exists, of course!)

Comment: I think I saw naming for stored procedure with `SP_` in one of Murach books

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to do this is to either use `merge` or to put a constraint on the table and trap for the error.

The reason `merge` is safer is because it is an atomic transaction.  Checking for existence and *then* doing the insert is dangerous, because someone else might have already inserted (or deleted) the row.  You can start playing with transaction semantics in the stored procedure, but why bother when SQL Server provides `merge`:

```
merge Pickup as target
using (select @PickupDate, @ClientId) as source(PickupDate, ClientId)
    on target.clientId = source.ClientId and year(source.PickupDate) = year(target.PickupDate) and month(source.PickupDate) = month(target.PickupDate)
when NOT MATCHED then
    insert(PickupDate, ClientId) values(source.PickupDate, source,ClientId);
```

You can read more about `merge`  [an](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can implement it using `IF NOT EXISTS`

```
create procedure sp_InsertPickup
    @ClientID int,
    @PickupDate date 
as 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Pickup 
                            WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
                            AND DATEPART(mm,PickupDate) = DATEPART(mm,@PickupDate)
                            AND DATEPART(yy,PickupDate) = DATEPART(yy,@PickupDate))
    BEGIN
        insert into Pickup (ClientID ,PickupDate )values (@ClientID,@PickupDate)
    END
begin
end
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works awesome but if I have insert for the same client  in same month last year  it just not inserting :(